# Running a django website without models.py and views.py

Tags: python, django

I did develop most of the front end but I am thinking to hire a freelance frontend developer(HTML, CSS and JS) to refine the design and make the site look professional. I am not yet comfortable to share my code with him. 
Is there any way in which he can run the django app without having models.py & views.py and work on html, css and js files.
Any leads on this matter is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Well the view is in essence what calculates the HTTP response, so without any views, there is not much the server does... Models are used to make data persistent in the database, so it *might* be possible to provide models that do not really work with a database, but again, somehow these models will need to satisfy the contracts the view use.

Comment: any utility which mimicks the view? I mean it needn't be an exact response. Some predefined response to all kinds of requests. Similar to a static site.

Comment: sure, you can replace all views, with a `HTTPResponse` that for example returns the a response you "recorded", or a sample response. And if you do not want to let anything persist, you can indeed make `models.py` blank.

Comment: Actually this explains in a better way, and I am looking a solution in this line. https://superuser.com/questions/785464/keeping-the-backend-code-hidden-from-frontend-developers

Answer (score 2):

He can build pure HTML/CSS/JS pages that you can use afterwards as your Django templates and extend as you wish. It depends of the complexity of your templates I guess.